# How to retrieve binary data from an image stored in a MongoDB document to then display it on the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, blob

The user has a form. He submits a file for his profile picture. The instance of `Blob` is being received by the server and its role is to upload in a document with MongoDB.

If I'm not mistaken, it is something like this:

```js
import { serialize } from "bson";

// ...

// with `db` my database
// and `picture` the Blob.
await db
        .collection("users")
        .updateOne({ email: user.email }, { $set: { picture: serialize(picture) } });
```

So far, storing data seems to be working fine. The problem occurs when I want to retrieve the data in order to display it on the client side.

I fetch the data and get this in my "users" collection :

```js
{
  email: "randomuser@foobar.com",
  picture : BinData(0, 'LgAAAAJuYW1lAAkAAABsb2dvLnBuZwABbGFzdE1vZGlmaWVkAADQM5z8XHhCAA==')
}
```

I'm not sure to understand what any of this means. All I want is to be able to transfer the data to the client side and then reconstruct the image in order to display it.

Note that the data is fetched server-side, using SvelteKit `load` function :

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({cookies}) => {
  const { user } = await getUser(cookies);
  console.log("user.picture =", user.picture);
  return {
    user: {
      picture: user.picture, // throws an error here because `picture` is non-serialisable
      email: user.email
    },
  }
}
```

In the console it looks like this :

```js
user.picture = new Binary(Buffer.from("2e000000026e616d6500090000006c6f676f2e706e6700016c6173744d6f6469666965640000d0339cfc5c784200", "hex"), 0)
```

#### What I tried

I tried to send the JSON of the buffer :

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({cookies})  =>{
  const { user } = await getUser(cookies);
  console.log("user.picture =", user.picture);
  console.log("user.picture =", user.picture!.buffer);
  return {
    user: {
      picture: user.picture!.buffer.toJSON(),
      email: user.email
    },
  }
}
```

And then, on the client side :

```js
onMount(() => {
  if (user.picture != undefined) {
    const arr = new Uint8Array(user.picture.data);
    console.log("on the client side : ", user.picture);
    console.log("in Uint8Array : ", arr);
    pictureURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([arr], { type: "image/png" }));
    console.log("pictureURL = ", pictureURL);
  }
});
```

In the console, it gives something like this :

```
pictureURL =  blob:http://localhost:5173/0ed581fc-87be-46ab-ade7-f44d78b98646
```

Therefore, I give that to the `img` element :

```html
<img src={pictureURL} alt="Profile picture" />
```

But the image is not displayed, only the `alt` description.

#### To sum up

I have the binary data of an image in a document of my database. How do I display the corresponding image with the fetched data?

Comment: Have you come out with a solution ?

Comment: @ziv I figured out a way to store images (that was my objective), if you're interested I came up with a SvelteKit template, just read the README and look at the code server-side : https://github.com/ThomasGysemans/sveltemongo